# Как удалить динамический компонент из переменной?

Tags: delphi

Как удалить динамический компонент из переменной?

Comment: [тут][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/74372/%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=74471#74471

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Плохо понятно, что откуда надо удалять. Для примера:

```
with TTable.Create(nil) do
try
    ...
finally
    Free;
end;
```

Создали таблицу, поиспользовали и удалили.